# Control range in VBA module when using AutoFill

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofill

I have a custom VBA function in Excel using two ranges

```
Function JOIN(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
```

I copy this function using AutoFill. I want the first range to be fixed (it's a header row) and the second range to be dynamic. How can that be done?

Comment: Can you provide more lines of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use relative/absolute references when using your function like you'd do with other functions/formulas:

> $A$1 = Headercell A1 will remain the one you want for r1
> A$1 = If you want to drag/autofill to the side as well
> $A1 = If you want the column to remain the same but not the row
> A1 = everything changes depending on where you drag it to

See [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-and-absolute-references-981f5871-7864-42cc-b3f0-41ffa10cc6fc)

In your case: `=JOIN($A$1;A2)` would be a use of your function

Could also go to row 1 of r1 but that's more of a hassle since headers aren't always on the first row.